Fallback to default if an atom doesn't exist
Beginner to ASP here :)
I need to define a default value for an atom when it isn't provided in the input.
% creating rooms
cost(create(room(R)), W) :- room(R), roomDomainNew(R), roomCost(W).

Here, if roomCost(W) is not defined, I want to fallback to a roomCost(0) zero cost. How do I do this?
Defining a roomCost(0) when the input has a roomCost of its own, leads to both co-existing.
roomCost(0).
roomCost(5).

In other languages, I could do something like:
finalRoomCost = 0
if roomCost:
    finalRoomCost = roomCost

and then I could use finalRoomCost. Is that possible here?

can you explain it better, also providing a full example with the expected output?

Related answer here, which says such mutability is not possible.

In ASP truth values do not change over time, either atoms are true or false for a specific answer set, they can not be overwritten.

So here's the solution I went with, using a #max directive:
roomCost(0).
finalroomCost(W) :- roomCost(0), #max {X, 1 : roomCost(X)} = W.

